# Java Regex match digital, character, comma, and quote...

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regular expressions...

I have a problem about the regular expression that will match a string only contains:

**0-9, a-z, A-Z, space, comma**, and **single quote**?

If the string contain any char that doesn't belong the above expression, it is invalid.

Is that something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s[a-zA-Z0-9,']");
Matcher m = p.matcher("to be or not");
boolean b = m.lookingAt();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that \s will match any whitespace character (including newlines, tabs, carriage returns, etc.) and not only the space character.

You probably want something like this:

"^[a-zA-Z0-9,' ]+$"

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the space inside the character class and allow more than one character:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\sa-zA-Z0-9,']*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("to be or not");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

Comment: You probably should anchor the regex with ^ and $ so that it doesn't partially match

Comment: @buckley: Thanks for the heads-up. I used the `.matches()` method instead.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your expression adding bounds:

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\s[a-zA-Z0-9,']+$");`

Now your can say `m.find()` and be sure that this returns `true` only if your string contains the enumerated symbols only. 
BTW is it mistake that you put `\\s` in the beginning? This means that the string must start from single white space. If this is not the requirement just remove this.

Comment: This requires that the string contains exactly one space at the first position and nowhere else.